# Selecting Duplicate values in ArcMap attribute table

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, sql

I am getting query errors while attempting to create a new selection (from a shapefile) by find duplicate values. My query is: `"GBIN" In (SELECT "GBIN FROM Ward_10 GROUP BY "GBIN" HAVING Count(*)>1)`

and the error is : `An Invalid SQL Statement was used.`

Comment: @BERA it's a .shp file

Comment: I don't think this works with a .shp, only SDE or feature class table. Have you tried changing it to a feature layer in a file geodatabase?
Two other suggestions: 1) If you only want to extract the duplicates, you could also create a separate column and use the field calculator to calculate an id for the duplicate records first, then use definition query to make a selection. 

2) Or, by creating a separate layer, use the summary as statistics tool to count the unique values in a column, then use the join table function to only keep the duplicate ones .

Comment: May not be relevant to the problem but you have an odd number of ", so that alone would mean your syntax is invalid.